# How to surround text with tag conditionally in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How to surround text with tag conditionally  in AngularJS?
for example:

```
function Controller($scope){
  $scope.showLink = true or false, retrieved from server;
  $scope.text = "hello";
  $scope.link = "..."
}
```

if {{showLink}} is false

```
<div>hello</div>
```

else

```
<div><a href="{{link}}">hello</a></div>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`ngSwitch`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSwitch) is suitable for that:

```
<div ng-switch="!!link">
    <a ng-href="{{link}}" ng-switch-when="true">linked</a>
    <span ng-switch-when="false">notlinked</span>
</div>
```

Comment: is it possible to eliminate <span>? only the text in it

Comment: Nope, not with `ngSwitch`. `span` has no styling modification, it is just inline text, why do you want to get rid of it?

Comment: Just curious. I try to set "ng-switch-when" onto "<div>" and after it with "ng-bind", hoping "ng-bind" only evaluated when "ng-switch-when" is matched.But it seems that angular is not works that way.

Comment: Angular *works* that way. You can definitely use `ngBind` along with `ngSwitchWhen`

Comment: I mean I was trying to set both "ng-switch" and "ng-switch-when" on "<div>". There's an error in console:"Argument '?' is required". Anyway, thank you.

Comment: I mean, at this point, why not wrap both elements in ng-if or something?  You stil have to repeat the inner text.

Comment: @emodendroket You are right, by the time this answer was written, Angular didn't have `ng-if`

Answer (score 11):

As far as I can tell there's no out-of-the-box feature to do this.  I wasn't really satisfied with the other answers because they still require you to repeat the inner contents in your view.

Well, you can fix this with your own directive.

```
app.directive('myWrapIf', [
  function()
    {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: false,
        compile:
          {
            pre: function(scope, el, attrs)
              {
                if (!attrs.wrapIf())
                  {
                    el.replaceWith(el.html());
                  }
              }
          }
      }
    }
]);
```

Usage:

```
<a href="/" data-my-wrap-if="list.indexOf(currentItem) %2 === 0">Some text</a>
```

"Some text" will be a link only if the condition is met.

Comment: Is there some way to make the condition accept an Angular expression - at the moment it looks like it's just pure Javascript.  I'd like to call a function or use a $scope object.

Comment: @CarlosP Yeah, declare a directive with isolate scope and then make that one of the scope object's fields with the value `'@'`.  I should probably rewrite this answer; this is not how I would do this today.

Comment: If you got a moment to rewrite the answer to demonstrate how to do that, it'd be really handy - thanks!

Comment: @Casey Would greatly appreciate the answer update you mentioned!

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
<div ng-show="!link">hello</div>
<div ng-show="!!link"><a href="{{link}}">hello</a></div>
```

Comment: one thing that I personally do not like about this approach is that it leaves the both elements in the DOM whereas `ng-switch` modifies DOM. as far as I know.

Comment: @akonsu ng-if does what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`ng-switch`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSwitch) directive.

```
<div ng-switch on="showLink">
    <div ng-switch when="true">
        <a ng-href="link">hello</a>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch when="false">
        Hello
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Modified version of Casey's answer to support AngularJS expressions:

```
app.directive('removeTagIf', ['$interpolate', function($interpolate) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
      if (scope.$eval(attrs.removeTagIf))
        el.replaceWith($interpolate(el.html())(scope));
    }
  };
}]);
```

Usage:

```
<a href="/" remove-tag-if="$last">{{user}}'s articles</a>
```

Comment: Works great, but i am not sure, would it work if the body of the tag uses expressions which point to promise/lazy loaded objects ? -- and in ur example, what if the value of {{user}} changes at run time, would the text update ?